# Joomla 1.6 errors galore on webpage

Tags: php, joomla

I recently picked up a project from a client to improve his website.  It's joomla website unfortunately and I don't know anything about Joomla, only have wordpress experience.

Now I finally got the site to work on localhost, the problem is that it's just error blocks everywhere, and I really hope some of the smart people on this site can help me.

And it's joomla 1.6 as far as I can see, the way I see that is in the readme.txt file it mentiones 1.6 repeatedly.

I get this error:

> > Warning: include() [function.include]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\fikile\templates\yoo_quantum\html\mod_custom\default.php on line 12

on this code:

```
include($warp['path']->path('layouts:'.preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($base, '/').'/', '', __FILE__, 1)));
```

and then the following error:

> > Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\fikile\templates\yoo_quantum\html\mod_search\default.php on line 12

on these two lines of code:

```
include($warp['path']->path('layouts:'.preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($base, '/').'/', '', __FILE__, 1)));
```

and

```
include($warp['path']->path('layouts:'.preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($base, '/').'/', '', __FILE__, 1)));
```

Please help, it seems the all the errors are related to the same kind of problem, but I don't have any clue what that problem is.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: I'm very confused as to why you're running Joomla 1.6. It's very old and was more of a Beta. You should upgrade your site to Joomla 2.5 which is exactly the same but with more security/bug fixes, along with more features. Please also note that this might actually solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Setting Site -> Global Configuration -> Server ->  Error Reporting to "System Default" might help, if it's not set that way already.

Comment: Thank you but where do I set that?

Comment: In the back end of the website. You can usually access the back-end of a Joomla website via www.sitename.com/administrator etc

Comment: Thanks Neil...when I click on global congiguration I get the following message:  Layout default_navigation not found.

Seems my problems are only starting